# How to use the new Vaadin Spring Boot addon together with Vaadin4Spring EventBus

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin4spring

The Vaadin team has currently released an addon which is as I understood based on the unofficial Vaadin4Spring addon:

Vaadin Spring Boot:
https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-spring-boot

Vaadin4Spring:
https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring

> Please note! As of February 2015, Vaadin is working on an official
>   Spring add-on which will be a small subset of Vaadin4Spring. Once the
>   official add-on is released, Vaadin4Spring will be converted into a
>   set of add-ons that provide features that the official add-on does not
>   have. You can follow the progress of the official add-on here:
>   https://github.com/vaadin/spring

However, the Vaadin Spring Boot is missing some cool features which Vaadin4Spring has (like said above by Petter Holmström, the author of Vaadin4Spring), like the EventBus framework, which is really useful.

Now I have set up a Maven project both with the Vaadin Spring Boot addon and the Vaadin4Spring addon:

```
    <!-- Vaadin Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Basically, I would like to use the features of both the frameworks (or better, I would like to use `Vaadin Spring Boot` as the main framework and use the `Vaadin4Spring EventBus` features together with it). The problem I have noticed, however, is that it seems that both the frameworks cannot coexist with each other yet.

If I add both the addons as above, when I run the application, no views and no UIs are found (below the log showing what I mean):

```
2015-03-01 22:07:22.001... SpringViewProvider: Looking up VaadinViews 
2015-03-01 22:07:22.006  WARN SpringViewProvider: No VaadinViews found ... 
...
2015-03-01 22:12:12.584  INFO: Checking the application context for Vaadin UIs 
2015-03-01 22:12:12.594  WARN: Found no Vaadin UIs in the application context
```

But the Views and the UI do exist! They are managed by the `Vaadin Spring Boot` addon (here is some sample code):

UI:

```
@SpringUI("")
@Theme("valo")
public class DemoUI extends UI {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 193481619798227053L;

    @Autowired
    private Greeter greeter;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private final SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

    private VerticalLayout layout;

    @Autowired
    public DemoUI(SpringViewProvider viewProvider) {
        this.viewProvider = viewProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {        
        layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        layout.setSpacing(true);
        setContent(layout);

        Label greetings = new Label(greeter.getGreeting());
        layout.addComponent(greetings);

        final CssLayout navigationBar = new CssLayout();
        navigationBar.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LAYOUT_COMPONENT_GROUP);
        navigationBar.addComponent(createNavigationButton("View Scoped View", ViewScopedView.VIEW_NAME));
        navigationBar.addComponent(createNavigationButton("UI Scoped View", UIScopedView.VIEW_NAME));
        navigationBar.addComponent(createNavigationButton("Another UI Scoped View", AnotherUIScopedView.VIEW_NAME));
        layout.addComponent(navigationBar);     

        final Panel viewContainer = new Panel();
        viewContainer.setSizeFull();
        layout.addComponent(viewContainer);
        layout.setExpandRatio(viewContainer, 1.0f);

        Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, viewContainer);
        navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);



    }

    private Button createNavigationButton(String caption, String viewName) {
        Button button = new Button(caption);
        button.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_SMALL);
        button.addClickListener(event -> { 
            try {
                getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(viewName);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // view with the given name is not mapped
                System.out.println("Not mapped view with name: " + viewName);
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

}
```

A view annotated with @SpringView:

```
@SpringView(DefaultView.VIEW_NAME)
public class DefaultView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2052937117362922764L;

    public static final String VIEW_NAME = "";

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
         // the view is constructed in the init() method()      
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        addComponent(new Label("This is the default view"));
    }

}
```

The same goes for other views. And everything works, when these two dependencies are removed from the pom.xml:

```
    <!-- Vaadin4Spring addon, the EventBus framework needs this addon -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-vaadin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Vaadin4Spring EventBus feature I would like to use with Vaadin Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-vaadin-eventbus</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Not allowing me to use the EventBus framework. Did anyone already explore the new addon too and had the same need? Did you find out how to integrate the two worlds? Or is it still early to use Vaadin4Spring tools into Vaadin Spring Boot and we should wait that the Vaadin4Spring features get converted into a set of addons which will complete `Vaadin Spring Boot` as is said in the first block I posted?

EDIT: I also tried to add a `@ComponentScan` annotation to the Spring Boot application class while having the three dependencies together, didn't help...

If I add `spring-vaadin` instead of `spring-boot-vaadin`:

```
        <!-- Vaadin4Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-vaadin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Vaadin4Spring EventBus framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-vaadin-eventbus</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Views and UIs are loaded and I can see them in the browser, but as soon as I want to start using an event bus, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaadinSpringBootDemoApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.vaadin.spring.events.EventBus$ApplicationEventBus demo.VaadinSpringBootDemoApplication.applicationEventBus; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.vaadin.spring.events.EventBus$ApplicationEventBus] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at demo.VaadinSpringBootDemoApplication.main(VaadinSpringBootDemoApplication.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.vaadin.spring.events.EventBus$ApplicationEventBus demo.VaadinSpringBootDemoApplication.applicationEventBus; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.vaadin.spring.events.EventBus$ApplicationEventBus] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.vaadin.spring.events.EventBus$ApplicationEventBus] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

It seems that the EventBus.* beans don't get registered inside the Spring IoC container. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `VaadinSessionScope` is not implemented yet in official spring4vaadin. You need to create that bean thought the unofficial spring4vaadin.

Your pom file:

```
<!-- Official Vaadin4Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Unofficial Vaadin4Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-vaadin</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Vaadin4Spring EventBus Addon -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-vaadin-eventbus</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

UI example:

```
@SpringUI("/ui")
@Title("Test")
@Theme("valo")
public class MainUI extends UI {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainUI.class);

    @Inject
    EventBus.UIEventBus eventBus;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        eventBus.subscribe(this);

        setContent(new Button("Create event", (e) -> {
            eventBus.publish(EventScope.UI, "Payload string.");
        }));
    }

    @EventBusListenerMethod
    public void onEvent(String str) {
        log.debug("Event received: {}", str);
    }
}
```

Application main class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableVaadinEventBus
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Bean
    static VaadinSessionScope vaadinSessionScope() {
        return new VaadinSessionScope();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The unofficial spring4vaadin dependency is temporary until the eventbus addon support the official spring4vaadin.

Comment: Man, you definitely made that. I guess I owe you a favour! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can have both. Try to include `"org.vaadin.spring:spring-vaadin:0.0.5-SNAPSHOT"` since `VaadinEventbusConfiguration` relies on internal classes.

Why do you need to include `"org.vaadin.spring:spring-boot-vaadin:0.0.5-SNAPSHOT"` ? If you really need it try to exclude `org.vaadin.spring.boot.VaadinAutoConfiguration` from @EnableAutoConfiguration.

EDIT:
You can get the addons with the official spring4vaadin in this branch:
https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/tree/feature/official_spring_support

Comment: You can also exclude `VaadinEventbusConfiguration` and create your own that relies on "com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot:${vaadin.spring.boot.version}" internal classes. 

`@Scope(value = VaadinUIScope.VAADIN_UI_SCOPE_NAME, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)`

Comment: I have tried to include `spring-vaadin-0.0.5-SNAPSHOT` instead of `spring-boot-vaadin`, views and UIs seem to be found, but the `EventBus.*` don't get @Autowired, please, check my edit

Comment: (I edited my answer) I just saw this now: https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring/tree/feature/official_spring_support

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Why did you give me the link to the GitHub repos of the Vaadin4Spring addon? I have already a copy of the `master` branch of the repository installed on my Maven local repository and I am picking 0.0.5 dependencies from it, do I have to remove it and use the `feature/official_spring_support` branch instead?

Comment: Yes, because `feature/official_spring_support` branch relies on official spring4vaadin and the `master` branch relies on the unofficial spring4vaadin. Compare the `spring-vaadin-eventbus` pom file of both branches so you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: All right, I have downloaded that branch, but it doesn't compile `mvn clean install` fails complaining about `vaadin-spring-boot`, saying that  vaadin-spring-boot **dependency is missing** for `spring-boot-vaadin`,

Comment: Nada, I have compiled the `feature/official_spring_support` branch but I still get the following exception: `Could not autowire field: org.vaadin.spring.events.EventBus$ApplicationEventBus demo.DemoApplication.applicationEventBus; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.vaadin.spring.events.EventBus$ApplicationEventBus] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.`

Comment: I will create a project to see more clearly what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

As an update to the accepted answer: the modules of the unofficial vaadin4spring add-on were renamed. Now one has to add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring-ext-core</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```